# Live Exchange Rates

Tags: ajax, api

Anyone know of a way using AJAX that I can use tp display some currency exchange rates on a site I'm building?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of Google API.. here is an article on the subject:

- [AJAX Currency Converter with Google API](http://www.techmug.com/ajax-currency-converter-with-google-api/)

But if you are ready to pay for a service, you might want to have a look at http://www.exchangerate-api.com/

Comment: Cheers all, this is just what i was looking for ;)

Comment: Google have deprecated this API )-:

Comment: @hippoetrail, it was not deprecated when the answer was written. Do you expect me to come and update my answer when an API is deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Yahoo!'s currency service. They have a web-based API you can use:

http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/currencies/converter/#from=GBP;to=EUR;amt=1

Comment: how to find there api documentation url? can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Use a site that has API to return currency rates preferably in JSON formats. Parse those and display on your site.

You may check out [here](http://www.exchangerate-api.com/).